# deleting dynamically allocated object that contains vector in C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl

I have a class

```
class ChartLine{

protected:
        vector<Point> line; // points connecting the line
        CString name; //line name for legend        
        CPen pen; //color, size and style properties of the line
};
```

where Point is a structure

```
struct Point{
    CString x;
    double y;    
};
```

In `main()` I dynamically allocate objects of type `ChartLine` with `new` operator.
If I use `delete` afterwards, will default destructor `~ChartLine()` properly dealocate (or clear) member `ChartLine::line`(which is vector btw) or I would have to clear that vector in `~ChartLine()` manually?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implicitly created destructor will call the destructor of all the members (in the reverse order they are declared in the class.) The `vector` will clean up after itself. You don't need to define a destructor yourself.

This is why you should prefer automatic allocation in combination with RAII. When objects clean themselves, your code as safer and easier. Hint: Don't use new and delete, put it in a smart pointer!

```
std::auto_ptr<int> p(new int(5));
boost::shared_ptr<int> p = boost::make_shared<int>(5);
```

Both of those will delete automatically, and now you're exception safe as well. (Note, the two above do not do the same thing. There are [more types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) of smart pointers as well.)

Comment: Although `auto_ptr` won't go into STL-type containers.  It was introduced for C++95, deprecated C++0x.  Short lifetime.

Comment: @GMan: Did you mean to refer to `make_shared()` et al or why the *"don't use `new`"*?

Comment: gf: Eh, I meant don't manage the pointer by hand. Hopefully this is clearer.

Comment: It does. *("Don't use new" still reads strange, but maybe i am just becoming pedantic :)*

Comment: @gf: Heh, I agree. Maybe I'll fix this post up someday. :P

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when a vector is destroyed, all the objects in the vector are destroyed. From the looks of things, your code should work as-is (though assuming the `CString` is the MFC one, some older versions of it had some memory leaks...)

Answer (score 1):

The only time you need to worry about vectors (or other containers) in a destructor is if they contain pointers to objects.  Since this isn't true in your case, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only time you ever need to call `delete` is after you've called `new`. Everything else is handled.