# Deallocation of a vector in C++

Tags: c++, stl, vector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [deleting dynamically allocated object that contains vector in C++ STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670558/deleting-dynamically-allocated-object-that-contains-vector-in-c-stl)

I have a struct like this

```
struct foo {
  vector<int> myvector;
};
```

Now, I create a pointer to foo, resize and insert some elements into the vector.

```
foo *myfoo = new foo;
myfoo->myvector.resize(100);
myfoo->myvector.push_back(0);
myfoo->myvector.push_back(1);
... // and so on
```

Now, before myfoo goes out of scope, I would have to deallocate the memory allocated to it with

```
delete myfoo;
```

My question is whether this would take care freeing myvector also? I have this particular query because now that myvector is resized, the STL library would presumably allocated the container in the heap. So, when I free up myfoo, I wouldn't want the memory allocated to myvector leaking.

Comment: _\*Grabs the popcorn and waits for the short, high-voted answers to roll in.\*_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Better? :D

Answer (score 7):

Yes, deleting `myfoo` will destroy all of its members too, which includes the `std::vector`. It's important to note that if you had pointers inside `foo`, only the pointers would be destroyed, not the objects they point to (unless of course you defined a destructor that did that job for you - which you should!).

It is mandated by the standard that after execution of the destructor, any non-static data members are destroyed also (§12.4/8):

> After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any automatic objects allocated within the body, a destructor for class `X` calls the destructors for `X`'s direct non-variant non-static data members, the destructors for `X`’s direct base classes and, if `X` is the type of the most derived class (12.6.2), its destructor calls the destructors for `X`'s virtual base classes.

The class `foo` has a defaulted destructor because no user-declared destructor is defined (§12.4/4):

> If a class has no user-declared destructor, a destructor is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4).

The destructor of `myfoo` is called when it is `delete`d (§5.3.5/6):

> If the value of the operand of the *delete-expression* is not a null pointer value, the *delete-expression* will invoke the destructor (if any) for the object or the elements of the array being deleted.

A *delete-expression* is an expression of the form:

> `::`<sub>opt</sub> `delete` *cast-expression*

Comment: Here, Foo has a defaulted destructor. How does the impementation keep track that a `delete foo` should cause a "chain" destruction of the vector inside it?

Comment: See the §12.4/8 quote. It doesn't matter whether it's defaulted or not. :)

Answer (score 4):

Calling `delete foo` will deallocate and call destructors (if applicable) on all members of `foo`, so yes.  If it didn't work this way the language would be much more difficult to use.

Answer (score 3):

The struct foo just holds the container of a vector. The items of the vector are allocated separately (usually on the heap) anyway.

The vector's destructor deletes the actual vector on the heap, and the vector is destroyed when the object is deleted.

Comment: I hate this phrase "on the heap" >.<

Comment: well, it is.. and the point is that the items themselves are allocated separately, not in the container itself.

Comment: The free store need not have anything to do with any "heap" whatsoever, and don't forget custom allocators. You have correctly identified, in your comment, that it is the _indirection_ that matters.

Comment: Yeap, but his example doesnt have custom allocators, hence are allocated on the heap.

Comment: You still have no way at all of knowing what memory is being used to implement the free store. I'm just picky about maintaining C++'s abstractions, that's all.

Comment: Okay, technically you're right. changed the wording

Answer (score 2):

Here is code example that answers your question.

```
#include <iostream>

struct bar {
    ~bar() {std::cout << "deleted bar" << std::endl;}
};

struct foo {
  bar b[10];  
};

int main() {
    foo* f = new foo();
    delete f;
}
```

The program will print "deleted bar" 10 times.